# portrait and landscape savedInstanceState

Tags: android, spinner

i have looked at various things to try and resolve this, however there is something i am missing with the onCreate or something.

i can move between portrait and landscape no problem and i can even save some of the data. my problem is in certain spinners.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("NS1", ns1.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("NS2", ns2.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("NS3", ns3.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("NS4", ns4.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("NS5", ns5.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("NS6", ns6.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("AS", announcespinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("FS", feastselectorspinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("CS", choirspinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("SS", saintspinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putBoolean("AK", akonly.isChecked());
    outState.putBoolean("PK", pkonly.isChecked());

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    feastselectorspinner.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("FS"));
    pkonly.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("PK"));
    akonly.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("AK"));

            //savedInstanceWait = false;
            //updateNewSongSpinners();
    ns1.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("NS1"));
    ns2.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("NS2"));
    ns3.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("NS3"));
    ns4.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("NS4"));
    ns5.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("NS5"));
    ns6.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("NS6"));

    saintspinner.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("SS"));
    choirspinner.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("CS"));
    announcespinner.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("AS"));

}
```

it updates everything except the nsx spinners. i believe it has somethign to do with the fact these are changeable.

if you check/uncheck the pkonly or akonly checkboxes or select a different selection in feastselectorspinner, then the nsx spinner adjust based on the database query which is performed below

```
private void updateNewSongSpinners(){
    if(!savedInstanceWait){
        db = new DatabaseHandler(Announcer.this);
        List<NewSong> listnewsong = db.getAkOrPkOrFeastSongs(akonly.isChecked(), pkonly.isChecked(), feastselectorspinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String t;
        list.add("Select New Song");
        for(NewSong lns : listnewsong){
            t = "";
            if(lns.getSongNum() < 10){
                t = "00";
            }else if(lns.getSongNum() < 100){
                t = "0";
            }
            t += Integer.toString(lns.getSongNum()) + " " + lns.getSongTitle();
            list.add(t);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Announcer.this, R.layout.list_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        //reset all spinners
        ns1.setAdapter(adapter);
        ns2.setAdapter(adapter);
        ns3.setAdapter(adapter);
        ns4.setAdapter(adapter);
        ns5.setAdapter(adapter);
        ns6.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

What am i missing that is preventing the nsx spinners from going back to their saved position. the NS1...NS6 values retrieved are the correct numbers. i cannot debug this because it wont debug on my phone and my emulator when i switch between portrait and landscape the emulator does not do anything.

the savedInstanceWait was used to see if there was a race condition. i could not find one.

i am at a loss. apparently the feastselectorspinner onClick() is being called after the onRestoreInstanceState(). which is causing the spinners to reset obviously. i do not know why the feastselectorspinner calls its function and none of the others do to reset their fields, but anyways. here is the fix which i would still like to know why it was calling the onclick() after the restore()

```
private void updateNewSongSpinners(){
    String str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6;

    str1 = ns1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    str2 = ns2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    str3 = ns3.getSelectedItem().toString();
    str4 = ns4.getSelectedItem().toString();
    str5 = ns5.getSelectedItem().toString();
    str6 = ns6.getSelectedItem().toString();


    db = new DatabaseHandler(Announcer.this);
    List<NewSong> listnewsong = db.getAkOrPkOrFeastSongs(akonly.isChecked(), pkonly.isChecked(), feastselectorspinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String t;
    list.add("Select New Song");
    for(NewSong lns : listnewsong){
        t = "";
        if(lns.getSongNum() < 10){
            t = "00";
        }else if(lns.getSongNum() < 100){
            t = "0";
        }
        t += Integer.toString(lns.getSongNum()) + " " + lns.getSongTitle();
        list.add(t);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Announcer.this, R.layout.list_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    //reset all spinners
    ns1.setAdapter(adapter);
    ns2.setAdapter(adapter);
    ns3.setAdapter(adapter);
    ns4.setAdapter(adapter);
    ns5.setAdapter(adapter);
    ns6.setAdapter(adapter);

    //if available keep previously chosen song
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i).equals(str1)) ns1.setSelection(i);
        if(list.get(i).equals(str2)) ns2.setSelection(i);
        if(list.get(i).equals(str3)) ns3.setSelection(i);
        if(list.get(i).equals(str4)) ns4.setSelection(i);
        if(list.get(i).equals(str5)) ns5.setSelection(i);
        if(list.get(i).equals(str6)) ns6.setSelection(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you set adapters first and then set the selection? It isn't clear from your posted code what is done first.

Comment: i tried that. the pkonly, akonly and feastselectorspinner all call the updateNewSongSpinners(). i even tried to call updateNewSongSpinners() manually but commented it out because it proved ineffective.

Comment: also i added this line just to add more confusion

    realTime.setText(String.valueOf(savedInstanceState.getInt("NS1")) + " " + String.valueOf(ns1.getCount()));

the result is a text box with "21 472" so there are multiple values in the spinner and i know which one to go to  but it does not go there

Comment: honestly i do not know what is causing this i even ran another string output and apparently the feastselectorspinner onClick() is activating after the onRestoreInstanceState(). i have no idea why. but because it gets called it then resets the spinners. the work around, which is good because it is better for the program is this. 

inside the updateNewSongSpinners() i remember the location of the currently selected loation then geenrate the new list and if the list contains the song that was selected before just keep it there is no need to reset that field.